# Application Development Process

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, reactjs

I am relatively new to web development. I am comfortable with HTML and CSS and somewhat comfortable with JavaScript. If I wanted to create a web app, would it be more efficient for me to write the functionality in JavaScript and then worry about implementing the code in an Angular or ReactJS app later? What is to stop me from creating a separate html file and js file for each component I'm using, make sure it works, and tying everything in together later? Thanks!

Comment: Nothing is stopping you. Angular and React are just Javascript frameworks (React has a little bit more with JSX). If you're planning to use one of those, it's best to pick one from the beginning because they'll dictate how you organize your code.

Comment: The primary reason I use a framework like angularJS is because it solves a lot of the repeating dev patterns that emerge when starting from scratch. That being said, it will probably be a little bit of a learning curve if you have not already learned some of the basics of Javascript and SPA development. And yes module development is useful especially when building more complex apps. Perhaps you should considering Test Driven Development which will introduce you to many of the concepts you need to learn in terms of Javascript and DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Angular and React are two separate things.
Angular is a framework that helps you to build Single Page Applications (SPA).
React is a User Interface library, not a framework.

Both comes with a lot of thing to learn, but it depends on what you want to do.

If you want to build JavaScript applications, I suggest you to learn ES6 first.